# Appsheet - special character inside columns' titles but not true

Tags: google-appsheet

I'm receiving the following message:

```
Table name 'IINR(finishes)' uses special characters that are used in expressions and formulas. Consider renaming the table to remove these special characters.
```

But I checked and there are no special characters inside any title.
I also tried to create a new app using a different GSheets, in which a copy paste the titles of the columns and in this case, no warning message.

What can it be the reason?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end (I didn't read well the message) the problem was on the title of the spreadsheet (table) and not at column level..